# Excel formula to look up a value using Row and Column values in a table

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

This is a two part question.  I want to lookup a price of an item based upon the effective date of the price. I've seen the vertical effective date examples but mine is somewhat different.  I have the Items in the first column (A).  The remaining columns contain a header with the effective date of the price.  Hopefully I'm able to attach the format example.  The reason I have the table formatted this way is that I don't want to duplicate the items when a new price is entered.  So, I want to provide the formula an ITEM and then select the current price base upon the effective date. Right now the table has 2 effective date columns.  So,The second question is how can I format the table so when I add a NEW price with a new effective date (an additional column) without having to change the look-up formula? Can the formula be formatted to be dynamic?

Thanks in advance for your input.

[image: Table Example]

Comment: I'm thinking MATCH the row you interested in and then lookup the value before the first blank cell to it's right. There are excel formulas to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment:

[image]

The formula in `B11`:

```
=INDEX(1:8,MATCH(A11,A:A,0),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(1:1),),0)-1)
```

As you notice I have populated `A1` to get this working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
=INDEX(1:1040000,MATCH("ITEM1",A:A,0),MATCH(1E+99,1:1))
```

If the date is always equal to or less than today I would use:

```
=INDEX(1:1040000,MATCH("ITEM1",A:A,0),MATCH(TODAY(),1:1))
```

Where the item can be replaced with a cell reference that contains the item to be looked up.

Comment: Thank you for the input.   This seems to work as I had originally requested.  However, I have a new challenge that I just thought of... The Workbook has multiple tabs.  Each tab is a month.   How do I preserve the rates that were in effect at the time of entry for a particular month?  Will the formula presented preserve the integrity of the rate that was entered previously?   I.E.  Here's what I have... I've created an expense workbook by month.  The reimbursement rate may change from time to time.  I want the rate entered (looked up) at the time of entry to be preserved.

Comment: If you change `TODAY()` to the date that you desire to pull it will work.  for Example any date between `10/5/19` and `11/15/19` will pull from column B in your example while anything after `11/16/19` will pull column C

Answer (score 0):

Please refers to JvdV's table, another shorter formula option

In `B11`, enter formula :

```
=LOOKUP(9.9E+307,INDEX(1:8,MATCH(A11,A:A,0),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your input. It was invaluable for working a solution to my problem.